# Unable to read/write to file in android

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I'm trying to get my app to write text into a text file from an EditText and read from it into a TextView. It never updated the TextView earlier and now the app is crashing. Any advise would be very appreciated!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CSCI598.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button rea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reads1);   
    rea.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button ap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.appends1);   
    ap.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void toast(String text)
{
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 

    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.reads1:

           try
            {
               FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
               BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
               String in;
               StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
               while ((in = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                   stringBuffer.append(in + "\n");
               }
               tv.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
                toast("File successfully loaded.");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                toast("Error loading file: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());

            }

        break;

    case R.id.appends1:

        String txt=et.getText().toString(); 

         try
            {
             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(txt); 
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

                toast("File successfully saved.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                toast("Error saving file: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        break;

  }

}

}
```

Comment: Where is it crashing? Did you manage to capture LogCat output leading up to the crash? Did you try running the code with your debugger on? Are you sure you have the correct file/dir permissions?

Comment: I'm running it with android emulator so unsure about permissions. Logcat is showing a ton of errors, I'm not sure what I should be looking at.. It crashes when I click 'Read'

Comment: See my update in the answer

Comment: Define 'unable' and 'crashing'. Post the stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the sdcard directory using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Try changing this line in you code:

```
String file = "sdcard/CSCI598.txt";
```

With:

```
String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CSCI598.txt";
```

Also, as @Yahya mentioned make sure you have this permission in your android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If this doesn't work. Try reading the file like this:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Then use your while loop as it is right now.

Write the file like this

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file, true);
 out.write(txt + "\n");
 out.close();
```

Comment: I just did that. It no longer crashes on 'read' but still doesn't update the TextView... I'm wondering if my append function has any issues or if it's even being stored?

Comment: try logging the stringBuffer.toString() before you set on textview to see if your string buffer is populating correctly

Comment: I added "ex.getLocalizedMessage()" into a toast after each attempted append or read. And I keep getting this... "Error saving file. SCSI598.txt contains a path separator" ??

Comment: did you try using the updated BufferedReader i added in the answer?

Comment: Yes @Peshal I've used your BufferedReader

Comment: Basically what i was saying was print the string buffer content before you set it to the textView this way we can figure out at least its getting the content from the file so basically before this line `t.setText(stringBuffer.toString());` try putting `System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString())` . If you can see the text in console we can simplify the problem

Comment: ^^ Did you read my comment about the localized error message from the toast? What's wrong with my path ?? I made a few changes and now getting "ENOENT: No such file or directory"

Comment: i see. do you have the file "CSCI598.txt" in the root of your sdcard? Or is it inside some other folder

Comment: I want my program to create the file if it doesn't exist... I thought the APPEND mode does that?

Comment: I see i will give you some working code snippet to write the file. Hold on

Comment: I tried the FileWriter method... and for the first time I got a successful toast !!! Still unable to read the file though -.-

Comment: Got it to read too with FileReader!! I'll post the new code... Unfortunately it's only posting one line of text when I click read.. Wonder if that's all that's stored or if it's only reading the last appended line.

Comment: i just updated the answer in file writer you need to put another parameter true to append

Comment: Works now flawlessly with the true parameter for FileWriter... Thanks a ton @Peshal !

Answer (score 0):

Provide crash log.

1. Have you given sdcard read write permission in your manifest xml file.

> `<`uses-permission
>   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`><`/uses-permission`>`

1. Instead of using hard coded path like **String file = "sdcard/CSCI598.txt";** use below

   > String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CSCI598.txt";
2. As you are using emulator have have you alot sd card space while creating AVD